# No receivers for action com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION

Tags: android

With Google Nexus phone I got this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No receivers for action com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION android

However the same code works on Moto G and Samsung mobiles

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just removed `GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);` from my activity and now it's working on google nexus phone...